# add a tag in front of some special lines of a text file

Tags: python

I have 2 files. The first contains 2000000 lines, each line contains a word and its part of speech tag in front of it.The second one contains some words, again each one in a line. I have to check if the words of the second file exist in the first file. If it exists, I have to add a "WSD" tag in front of that word, else, just write the line without any change. the code I wrote works, but it prints each line more than 50 times.How can I change it so that it writes each line only once?

```
with open ("c:/python34/h.txt", encoding="utf-8") as f1:
    f1=f1.readlines()
with open ("c:/python34/WSD.txt", encoding="utf-8") as f2:
    f2=f2.read().split()
with open ("result.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f3:
     for line in f1:
         for i in f2:
             if i in line:
                 line = line + "\t\t\t\t" + "WSD"
             else:
                 line = line
                 f3.write(line + "\n")
                 f3.write(" ")
```

The language is persian.
A snippet of the first file:

ستاره شناسان                                      N_PL
مي گويند                                          V_PRS
كه                                                CON
باد                                               NOUN
ممكن                                              ADJ_SIM
است                                               V_PRE
اولين                                             ADJ_SUP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things.

1. Your write to the file should not be in the else loop.  The write should be part of the outer for loop.
2. Your second file.write() invocation adds an unnecessary space before each line.

I rewrote it for you and simplified it.

```
with open ("c:/python34/h.txt", encoding="utf-8") as f1:
    f1=f1.readlines()
with open ("c:/python34/WSD.txt", encoding="utf-8") as f2:
    f2=f2.read().split()
with open ("result.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f3:
     for line in f1:
         for i in f2:
             if i in line:
                 line = line + "\t\t\t\t" + "WSD"
         f3.write(line + "\n")
```

There is one more thing.  The way you have this code the WSD is added to the end of the line, not in front of the word like you said.

You also should consider the behavior of your program when multiple words are found in a single line.  As currently written WSD will be added multiple times when that happens.

Comment: thanks, but it didn't make any difference. Again each line is written a lot of times.

Comment: Sorry I fixed it.  The line was being written multiple times because you were writing to the file as part of the inner for loop.